Not authorized to perform operation (udisk-error-quark, 4) - Gnome Disks on DietPi (RPI2B)
I am having some issues mounting some partitions with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running DietPi. The software utilized is GNOME Disks.

Thank you so much for all of your time and energy. I immensely appreciate any support you may be able to provide.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/399768/encrypted-disk-wont-unlock-anymore-not-authorized-to-perform-operation-udisks

@ChanganAuto This device is not encrypted

Then provided link has answers applicable to the same error, regardless of encryption.

@ChanganAuto There are a few different solutions listed on the page.
The main one is to utilize sudo.
This is concerning, as it does not allow for other application to utilize it and does not solve the issue that the user specified is unable to mount a disk. It mounts it under /media/root instead of as the user.
As such, the question does not provide an applicable solution.
Thank you you so much for your support.
